# run option gone from Microsoft Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compilation, visual-studio-2010

I think I accidentally changed some settings in my MSVC 2010 compiler and now I can't find the compile and execute option. Also when I hit the tab button for indentation an arrow(->) appears. I wonder whats wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset editor blunder, just hit <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+8</kbd>, from inside the text editor itself. This is toggle-able option, which can be used to see white spaces. Sometimes useful!

Answer (score 2):

Use the tools menu "Import and Export Settings" then select "Reset all Settings" to reset the settings back to default.